# Liferay 6.0.5 deployment

Tags: liferay-6

When I put my war in deploy folder. 
It automatically gets removed.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 .

I tried many times deploying before and after 
tomcat start. Nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly what's supposed to happen. When deployment works, Liferay will remove the file from the deploy folder. The natural state of the folder is empty. Only if deployment faild, yhe plugin will stay in the folder.

You'll find it in tomcat's webapps folder.